# C# TableLayoutPanel fill

Tags: c#, size, fill, tablelayoutpanel

In the TableLayoutPanel, by default, the last element in a row or column takes up the remaining space. How can I achieve a layout where the penultimate or any other element takes up as much space as possible, and among others, the last element takes up only as much space as is necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the other rows are set.
Assuming all other rows are auto-sized or of fixed size, setting the penultimate row's size to 100% does what you want. The designers generated code looks like this:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but dash is right (that Dominique was first) :P

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel was in first. I was spooked when I posted my answer and saw another one there very similar!

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this using Windows Forms and .Net Framework 4;

The simplest solution seems to be to create a table layout panel, and embed your controls in each of the columns. Once done, set the size of all of the columns to "AutoSize".

Then take your penultimate column and set the size to be "100%"

Here's the code from my designer:

```
    tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
```

Be sure to embed your controls first, as, if there is no content in the other cells, setting the penultimate column to size 100% then makes it tricky to use the designer to put controls in the empty cells as the 100% column effectively "steals" their space.